# How does a gravity defying stand comes in equilibrium?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, equilibrium, statics

The gravity defying wine bottle stand are now becoming very common these days.

[image]

Can someone explain in detail the physics involved here?

[Here](https://youtu.be/hrnwdO7V27w) is a video that gives details about its making.

Answer (score 1):

> The gravity defying wine bottle stand are now becoming very common these days.

**The bottles do not defy gravity**. The normal force exerted on the support (contact area between the wood and the table) equals weight of the two bottles plus weight of the wood. The bottles would tip over if there is some torque about one of the edges of the area of support.

The trick is to place **center of gravity** of the system within the **area bounded by the support** (check the figure below). In that case there will be **no torque** and the system will remain at rest, i.e. the bottles will not tip over.

[image: Center of gravity]

<sup>Source: H. D. Young, R. A. Freedman, "University Physics with Modern Physics in SI Units", 15th ed., 2019.</sup>

Comment: @gpuguy Thickness contributes to both mass of the stand (minor effect) and area of support (large effect). Larger the area of support, more space you have to position the center of gravity. It would be very difficult to balance something on a needle.

Comment: great. Since I wanted to rephrase my argument I deleted this comment which was about the role played by surface area of the stand.

Comment: @gpuguy Do you have your answer now?